# How to monitor when a server cannot reach domain controller

Tags: active-directory, monitoring

We had a situation today when our infrastructure team demoted a domain controller. For some reason our database server (Sql Server) could no longer access any of the remaining domain controllers. All our sql jobs started failing and we did not receive any notifications that they were failing (possibly because it could not reach a DC).

So my question is there a robust way we can monitor servers and raise an alert if they cannot reach a domain controller?

Cheers,

Charlie

Comment: What monitoring software are you using to monitor your servers in general?

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it would be as follows:

Have script scheduled to run locally every x mins/hours which pings yourdomain.local on any of your critical services servers. In the event of failure alert administrator.

I know it would be better to have a centrally managed solution but your testing from servers to your domain controller. I guess you could use script on one server using psexec to run ping remotely on any of the reliant servers.